# How to save Json file as arrayOfObjects instead of setsOfObjects

Tags: json, azure, pyspark

I would like to copy a Json file array of objects to a target directory using Pyspark maintianing the same format.
Here attached is Json file array of objects( See attached file):
[Json File array of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQwr0.jpg)

At the moment the format changes to a set of objects. [Json file set of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hleoY.jpg).

I ran these statements without any positive outcome:

```
df.spark.read("/path/source/")
df.write.mode("overwrite").json("/path/target/")
```

How can I copy the original file to a directory using same format array of objects?

Comment: Are you using databricks? If you just wanna move files around, you can use dbutils.fs.mv()
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/databricks-utils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced this and I got **same JSON file set of objects** when I read the JSON **after saving to another folder**.

Here `df` is the **original dataframe** of JSON file array of objects and I had saved it to `outputjson.json`(target json) file.

[image]

But when I avoided the **multiline** in reading the target JSON, I got the dataframe as original.

[image]

Remove the multiline when reading the second dataframe, then you can get the original JSON data.

Also, rather than doing all this you can directly **move or copy** the original JSON file from one folder to another in DBFS as suggested by **@ARCrow** in comments.

**Example:**

[image]

Here I have used multiline because it is a raw JSON file not a JSON file saved from dataframe.